# A problem about the implementation of Bezier curve

Tags: plotting, evaluation, parametric-functions

I implemented the [**Bezier** curve](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/B%C3%A9zier_curve) like *built-in*  `BezierCurve` as follow:

> `SplineDegree -> d` specifies that the underlying polynomial basis should have maximal degree `d`.
>
> `Method` is a option that determining which algorithm was used.
>
> `ControlPoints` is a option that determining whether show the *control points*
>
> `SplineClosed` is an option that specifies whether spline curves or surfaces should be closed.
>
> `CAGDBezierCurve` by default represents a composite cubic Bézier curve.
>
> With `SplineDegree -> d`, `CAGDBezierCurve` with `d + 1` control points yields a simple degree - `d` Bézier curve.With fewer control points, a lower - degree curve is generated. With more control points, a composite Bézier curve is generated.

---

UPDATE for 3D CASE

```
Options[CAGDBezierCurve] = {SplineClosed -> False, 
 SplineDegree -> Automatic, ControlPoints -> False, Method -> Automatic};

CAGDBezierCurve[pts : {{_, _} ..} | {{_, _, _} ..}, opts : OptionsPattern[]] :=
 Module[{sc, sd, cp, Bezier, ptgroup},
  sc = OptionValue[SplineClosed];
  sd = OptionValue[SplineDegree] /. Automatic -> 3;
  cp = OptionValue[ControlPoints];
  Bezier =
   ToExpression@OptionValue[Method] /. Automatic -> BezierDefinition;
  ptgroup = Partition[pts, sd + 1, sd, 1, {}];
  If[Length@First@pts == 2,
   ParametricPlot[
    Evaluate[Bezier[#, u] & /@ ptgroup], {u, 0, 1},
    Evaluate@
     (Sequence @@
       FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]]), 
      Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All,
    Epilog -> If[cp, {Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}, {}]],
   Show[
    {ParametricPlot3D[
      Evaluate[Bezier[#, u] & /@ ptgroup], {u, 0, 1},
      Evaluate@
       (Sequence @@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot3D]]), 
      Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All],
    Graphics3D[
     If[cp, {Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]]}]
  ]
]
```

---

```
BezierDefinition[pts_, u0_?NumericQ] :=
 Nest[
  MovingAverage[
   ArrayPad[#, 1], {u0, 1 - u0}] &, {1}, Length[pts] - 1].pts

deCasteljau[pts_, u0_?NumericQ] :=
 Nest[
  MovingAverage[#, {1 - u0, u0}] &, pts, Length@pts - 1]
```

Owning to the `HoldAll` attribute of `ParametricPlot`, so I must used the `Evaluate` three times in the `ParametricPlot`.

In addition, I know the `ParametricPlot` owns the `Evaluated-> True` option, so I refactor(remove `Evaluate`) the part of `ParametricPlot` as below:

```
ParametricPlot[
 Bezier[#, u] & /@ ptGroup, {u, 0, 1},
 Evaluated -> True,
 Sequence @@
  FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]],
 Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
 Epilog -> If[cp, {Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}, {}]
]
```

However, it failed.

#### TEST

```
pts = {{0, 0}, {1, 1}, {2, -1}, {3, 0}, {4, -2}, {5, 1}};

CAGDBezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> #1, SplineClosed -> #2, 
 ControlPoints -> True] & @@@ {{2, True}, {3, False}} // Row

Graphics[{Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts], Black, 
 BezierCurve[pts, SplineDegree -> #1, 
  SplineClosed -> #2]}] & @@@ {{2, True}, {3, False}} // Row
```

[image]

```
pts1 = {{0, 0, 0}, {1, 1, 1}, {2, -1, 1}, {3, 0, 2}, {5, 3, 4}};

CAGDBezierCurve[pts1, SplineDegree -> 4, ControlPoints -> True]
```

[image]

---

#### QUESTION

- Is there a solution to deal with avoiding using `Evaluate` function many times?
- Why the `PlotRange -> All` cannot show the entire graph?

Comment: I sometimes use `ParametricPlot @@ {args...}`, or `Block[{u}, ParametricPlot @@ {args...}]`, to get around `Evaluated`.

Comment: @MichaelE2,  I see. By the `ParametricPlot @@ {args...}`, `the args` would be evalauted firstly.THX:)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

I have reworked your code somewhat. I hope what I have done will help you with your problem.

```
BezierDefinition[pts_, u0_?NumericQ] := 
  Nest[MovingAverage[ArrayPad[#, 1], {u0, 1 - u0}] &, {1}, Length[pts] - 1].pts

ClearAll @ CAGDBezierCurve;
Options[CAGDBezierCurve] = 
  {SplineClosed -> False, SplineDegree -> Automatic, 
   ControlPoints -> False, Method -> Automatic};
CAGDBezierCurve[
     pts : {{_, _} ..}, 
     opts : OptionsPattern[{CAGDBezierCurve, ParametricPlot}]] := 
   Module[{sc, sd, cp, Bezier, ptGroup},
   sc = OptionValue[SplineClosed];
   sd = OptionValue[SplineDegree] /. Automatic -> 3;
   cp = OptionValue[ControlPoints];
   Bezier = 
    ToExpression @ OptionValue[Method] /. Automatic -> BezierDefinition;
   ptGroup = 
     If[sc, 
        Partition[Append[pts, First@pts], sd + 1, sd, 1, {}], 
        Partition[pts, sd + 1, sd, 1,
        {}]];
   ParametricPlot[Bezier[#, u] & /@ ptGroup, {u, 0, 1}, 
     Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]],
     Axes -> False, PlotRange -> All, 
     Epilog -> If[cp, {Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}, {}]]]

CAGDBezierCurve[pts,
  SplineDegree -> #1, SplineClosed -> #2, ControlPoints -> True, 
  ImageSize -> Medium, PlotRange -> {{0., 5.}, {-2., 1.}}, 
  PlotRangePadding -> {.25, .3}] & @@@ {{2, True}, {3, False}} // Column
```

[image: curves]

**Discussion**

1. I have reduced the number of Evaluates to one; the others were simply not necessary, at least in V10.2. Over the last several releases *Mathematica*'s plotting functions have become much smarter about evaluating held arguments internally.
2. I have corrected mistakes made in handling options. The documentation on option handling is a disgrace, so don't feel bad about not getting it right.
3. I have removed your alternative pattern for 3D points; there is no way your function as currently written can handle such points.
4. I have not done anything about the clipping of `Epilog` graphics. The example output shown above demonstrates the missing graphics can be revealed by explicitly giving the plot range and increasing the plot range padding. This is a work-around, not a solution. Unfortunately, `PlotRange -> All` does not look at the epilog graphics when computing the plot range.

I know of no easy fix for the plot range problem. You might try to compute the needed space in your function and set the plot range explicitly.

#### Update

ShutaoTang has posted an answer with incorporates the points made above and also extends his `CAGDBezierCurve` function to handle 3D control points. I believe I can improve on his code a little by consolidating the two calls to `Show` into a single call simply by recognizing that the heads of expressions can be variables that get evaluated in the same way arguments do.

```
ClearAll@CAGDBezierCurve;
Options[CAGDBezierCurve] = 
  {SplineClosed -> False, SplineDegree -> Automatic, ControlPoints -> False, 
   Method -> Automatic};
CAGDBezierCurve[
    pts : {{_, _} ..} | {{_, _, _} ..}, 
    opts : OptionsPattern[{CAGDBezierCurve, ParametricPlot, ParametricPlot3D}]] :=
  Module[{sc, sd, cp, Bezier, ptgroup},
    sc = OptionValue[SplineClosed];
    sd = OptionValue[SplineDegree] /. Automatic -> 3;
    cp = OptionValue[ControlPoints];
    Bezier = 
      ToExpression @ OptionValue[Method] /. Automatic -> BezierDefinition;
    ptgroup = 
      If[sc, 
        Partition[Append[pts, First@pts], sd + 1, sd, 1, {}], 
        Partition[pts, sd + 1, sd, 1, {}]];
     Block[{u, plotF, graphF},
       With[{curves = Bezier[#, u] & /@ ptgroup},
         {plotF, graphF} =
           If[Length @ First @ pts == 2,
             {ParametricPlot, Graphics}, 
             {ParametricPlot3D, Graphics3D}];
         Show[{
           plotF[curves, {u, 0, 1},
             Evaluate@FilterRules[{opts}, Options[plotF]], Axes -> False, 
             PlotRange -> All], 
           graphF[If[cp, {Green, Line[pts], Red, Point[pts]}]]}]]]]
```

Comment: @MichaelE2. I tried that, but it did not show the full extent of the epilog graphics.

Comment: My mistake.  I guess `Show[ParametricPlot[...], Graphics[epilog stuff], PlotRange -> All]` is how `CAGDBezierCurve` should be written.

Comment: THX  a lot for conrecting the option mistake `opts : OptionsPattern[{CAGDBezierCurve, ParametricPlot}]`. Now for the clipping of `Epilog` graphics, I have a idea that ultilizing the `Graphics[{...}]` and `Show`.

Comment: BTW, I would know why the code `Evaluate @Sequence @@
 FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]]` could be replaced with `Evaluate @ FilterRules[{opts}, Options[ParametricPlot]]`

Comment: @ShutaoTang. Options may be nested in lists any to any depth. The list structure is flattened by the internal graphics code.